# The link between an API, DAL and BLL

Tags: java, dependencies, multi-module

This is my first post so I hope I am clear enough about my problem.
So, I have a project with several modules. The connection between three of them confuses me:
   - API - some interfaces for data retrieval, etc.
   - BLL - the business logic layer
   - DAL - where I implement the methods from API.
I can't seem to understand how am I supposed to get any data in BLL from DAL through API, since my teacher says there SHOULDN'T be any connection(dependency) between BLL and DAL, only between BLL and API and DAL and API. He(my teacher) also says I shouldn't implement any methods from API in BLL, but also says that BLL needs the data read by the methods implemented in DAL. So the question is - how do I access DAL only through API?